# dataBase does not update

Tags: android, database, model

my database cant update

this is my updateMethod

```
  public long updateInfo(ModelInsertInfo modelInsertInfo) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID,modelInsertInfo.getId());
    values.put(KEY_yearWater, modelInsertInfo.getYearWater());
    values.put(KEY_MonthWater, modelInsertInfo.getMonthWater());
    values.put(KEY_DayWater, modelInsertInfo.getDayWater());
    values.put(KEY_HourWater, modelInsertInfo.getHourWater());
    values.put(KEY_MinWater, modelInsertInfo.getMinWater());
    return db.update(TABLE_Insert_Info, values, "" + KEY_ID + "= " + modelInsertInfo.getId() + "", null);
}
```

and this codes in activity

```
ModelInsertInfo modelInsertInfo = new ModelInsertInfo();
                    ActionInsertInfo actionInsertInfo = new ActionInsertInfo(getApplicationContext());

                    modelInsertInfo.setYearWater(yearFC);
                    modelInsertInfo.setMonthWater(monthFC);
                    modelInsertInfo.setDayWater(day1);
                    modelInsertInfo.setHourWater(hour);
                    modelInsertInfo.setMinWater(min);

                    long check = actionInsertInfo.updateInfo(modelInsertInfo);

                    if (check > 0) {
                        Snackbar.make(null, ":)", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(ActivityDetails.this, ":(((", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

when select button return -1 and i use external database 
thanks for help me :)

Comment: it's because you are not setting ID to `modelInsertInfo` before updating. i am pretty sure `modelInsertInfo.getId()` returns null (or 0 if it's return type is int)

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit when set info to model i forget set id it work thank you.

Comment: Happy to help.. cheers.